# How to customise a third party library or (Django app)?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am working on Django-Oscar,

For customizing oscar apps, Oscar provides us with a very amazing management command, 
python manage.py oscar_fork_app customer oscar_apps

This clones the oscar app, and create a local version of oscar.apps.customer. Now we can modify Models, views, in an easy way.
I am looking for the same alternative in Core Django.

What I am trying to achieve?

I have a requirement, where I have installed [djstripe library](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe). with pip command.
now I want to customize a [management command](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/management/commands/djstripe_init_customers.py) from that library.

I did my R&D over this and got to know that I can clone from git and then run 
pip install -e setup.py

But sadly, after cloning djstripe I got to know that there is no setup.py available.

How can I customize a third-party library like djstripe according to my needs?

Comment: You can't do this for third party libraries that don't explicitly allow forking the way Oscar does. In this particular case, the management command you want to modify has two lines of functional code - why not just write your own to replace it?

Comment: okay, thank you sir.